# converting Sql in Magento-2?

Tags: database, magento2.2, php-7

How to use below query in magento2 format for getting collection.

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);
```

If anyone knows please explain me...